# Are both these sentences in different orders correct?

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clauses, subject-auxiliary-inversion

The original sentence is below.

> When you are studying any matter, or considering any philosophy, ask yourself only **what are the facts** and **what is the truth that the facts bear out**.

I would like to know if the sentence below in a different order is correct as well.

> When you are studying any matter, or considering any philosophy, ask yourself only **what the facts are** and **what the truth that the facts bear out is**.

I am not a native English speaker and there is so much basic stuff I am confused about like this. Any explanations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate. This is a total different one. Sometimes I heard people say "I don't know what it is." and also "I don't know what is it.". It is a pity that people right away downed this question into a duplicate without enough discussion.